# Behavior of OrderdDict

Tags: python, dictionary

I was answering one of the questions on SO and I stumbled upon this behavior of `OrderedDict`, which I could not explain. It goes as follows
You have a dict that looks like this:

```
exmpl  = OrderedDict([(30, ('A1', 55.0)), (31, ('A2', 125.0)), (32, ('A3', 180.0)), (43, ('A4', float('nan')))])
```

The goal is to remove the dictionary entries which has `nan` in it, which can be accomplished in the following ways:

1. By use of `for` loop

   ```
   for k,v in dict_cg.items():
     if np.isnan(v[1]):
        exmpl.pop(k)
   print exmpl
   ```

   and the output will be

   ```
    OrderedDict([(30, ('A1', 55.0)), (31, ('A2', 125.0)), (32, ('A3', 180.0))])
   ```
2. Through dictionary comprehension method (while defining it as an OrderedDict) as follows

   ```
   exmpl = OrderedDict({k:v for k, v in dict_cg.items() if not np.isnan(v[1])})
   print exmpl
   ```

which returns

```
  OrderedDict([(32, ('A3', 180.0)), (30, ('A1', 55.0)), (31, ('A2', 125.0))])
```

Can someone educated me, as to why the dictionary jumbled in the second case turns up jumbled.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are creating an ordinary dictionary with a dictionary comprehension, which has arbitrary order, which you pass to the `OrderedDict` constructor *afterwards*.

Answer (score 2):

Like @timgeb mentioned, in Python versions before 3.6, dictionary order is effectively random. If you want to still use a comprehension in Python 3.5 and below, you can use a list comprehension of tuples instead:

```
OrderedDict([(k, v) for k, v in dict_cg.items() if not np.isnan(v[1])])
```

Comment: Or better yet, a generator comprehension. No need to build a list.